# bootstrap column ordering grid mobile desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have 3 divs that I want to arrange on desktop in a special manner.

the 3 divs are:

- signup
- new post
- news

in mobile is should stacked on each other like this:

```
signup
new post
news
```

but in desktop it should be like this:

```
[news - 8 size] [signup - 4 size]
                [new post - 4 size]
```

I used bootstrap push and pull features but still cant find the magic solution.

My code: http://codepen.io/tzookb/pen/beEvVd

Comment: Why not use 2 rows?

Comment: Please tell me how, no idea how to move the rows :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xu47j54f/

Plenty of ways of doing this...

You could use a nested row within the second column, as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          Column 2 - Row 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          Column 2 - Row 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT - as per comments below, combining push and pull should give you the desired output of row ordering at mobile size: https://jsfiddle.net/xu47j54f/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          Column 2 - Row 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          Column 2 - Row 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      Column 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but in the example you gave as I need, it means that "column 2 - row 2 should be on top left.. in your version it is still on the bottom in the right

Comment: second example is the same... take a look at my description and see how the divs should align

Comment: @TzookBarNoy, You could use a combined pull / push approach in that case: https://jsfiddle.net/xu47j54f/1/

Comment: previous  comment seems legit, let me test that :)

Comment: @TzookBarNoy No problem - I've added it in my answer now too.